# PHPMYADMIN returns result, PHP Query doesnt

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I created a query in ***PhpMyAdmin*** to pick one random online member that is part of a certain group. It works fine in ***PhpMyAdmin*** and does exactly what I want. However, when I run this query using ***PHP*** it does not return anything. I simply get `'NULL'` when I use `var_dump($result)`.

```
$sql= "SELECT
ow_base_user_online.userId,
ow_base_authorization_user_role.roleId
FROM
ow_base_user_online
INNER JOIN ow_base_authorization_user_role ON ow_base_authorization_user_role.userId = ow_base_user_online.userId
WHERE
ow_base_authorization_user_role.roleId = 14
ORDER BY
RAND()
LIMIT 1";
$result = OW::getDbo()->queryForList($sql);
```

Please, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try to debug the query's function.

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but, did you select the database prior to the query?

Comment: The query function works okay, I've used it several times in the script. It should return an array to be used, but it doesn't seem to be returning anything at all :(

Comment: @SeanDarrenDawn - Does your database class include something that will return the error from the database? That should tell you what the issue is.

Comment: @andrewsi, no it doesn't :/
It's so weird I;ve never had this issue before.

Comment: Try a simpler query. Reduce yours' to the max and then add your e.g. joins step by step.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please does anyone have any ideas?
```

Yes, use error reporting from your mysql query and see what it returns. Check PHP errors too (can get auth warnings to show something daft like bad user/password etc).

Also, for testing, try removing the class you use and stick the DB connection code above that query and query all direct from a test script. If it works fine, then your query is ok, as is the connection and credentials.
From there you can work backwards checking the class you have.

Comment: Thanks James, I will give that suggestion a go.